# Android app downloaded from Play Store is not the app version i end up playing

Tags: android, unreal-engine4

**Issue:**

An old version of my app is being run on my phone, regardless of a new version of the app being downloaded from Play Store.

**Question:**

- Has anyone else had this issue?
- Was there a fix to it?

**Context:**

I'm using Unreal Engine.

For the last 15 versions of my application, I have been building apk and obb files, uploading them to Play store on internal track, and then downloading the app through the play store to my Google Pixel 3 XL phone.

This has worked perfectly. until...

Yesterday, I needed to debug a lighting issue so plugged in my phone with a usb cable, hit the Launch to Pixel 3 button and debugged the issue.

That night, i did the usual, package my game up and upload to Play Store.

In the morning, I hit the update button in the Play store and when i went to play it, my new textures, lighting, speed of sequencer etc changes, were not on the application that i was now seeing on my phone?

I thought i must have been tired when I uploaded too late at night and made a mistake, so i re-uploaded the files and released back onto the store, a few moments later, the updated message came through from Play Console and i hit the download button again. Same issue?

- I ran `adb shell dumpsys package com.Example.Name | grep version` in my bash window and low and behold, the correct version was installed on my phone?
- I tried to uninstall the app using the phone's uninstall and also `adb uninstall`.
- I tried clearing the Play store cache out and restarting my phone.

I then asked one of my testers to download the update on their phone... The correct version of the app came through for them?

The realisation that using Unreal Engine Launch button has somehow broken the Play Store cache or App cache had started to become apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since found that if you goto files app on the phone, make sure it's looking at internal storage, there is an unreal engine folder. Inside, you can delete cached obb files which are then downloaded correctly next time from the play store.